# Polymer- add behavior without creating a custom element?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

In Polymer 1.1, this is my index.html

```
 <template is="dom-bind" id="app">
      <paper-drawer-panel force-narrow id="the-drawer">
        <paper-header-panel drawer>
          <paper-toolbar></paper-toolbar>
            <div> Drawer content... </div>
        </paper-header-panel>
        <paper-header-panel shadow="true" 
          mode="waterfall-tall"
          main
          class="fit">
          <paper-toolbar>
```

I would like to add `iron-resizable-behavior` to catch resize events. The thing is, I don't want to make a custom element to do it. Is it possible to add `iron-resizable-behavior` to index.html without making a custom element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [Behaviors guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/behaviors.html), it mentions that the whole purpose for behaviors is for them to be extended by custom elements, so you can't use them without extending them in an element.

You could either create a simple element which extends `iron-resizeable-behavior` and fires events you can listen to or just make that entire `dom-bind` into an element.

Then again, depending on what you need to do, using [iron-media-query](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-media-query) might be enough.

Comment: Cool, how can I catch the `iron-media-query`  `query-matches="{{queryMatches}}"` variable `queryMatches` without a custom element?

Comment: @dman queryMatches notifies so you can listen to its `queryMatches-changed`event (it could be called `query-matches-changed` though, I'm not really sure which one it'd be)